# calculate pairwise simhash "distances"

Tags: python, scikit-learn, simhash

I want to construct a pairwise distance matrix where the "distances" are the similarity scores between two strings as implemented [here](https://github.com/sangelone/python-hashes). I was thinking of using sci-kit learn's pairwise distance method to do this, as I've used it before for other calculations and the easy parallelization is great.

Here's the relevant piece of code:

```
def hashdistance(str1, str2):
    hash1 = simhash(str1)
    hash2 = simhash(str2)

    distance = 1 - hash1.similarity(hash2)

    return distance   


strings = [d['string'] for d in data]
distance_matrix = pairwise_distances(strings, metric = lambda u,v: hashdistance(u, v))
```

`strings` looks like `['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`.

When I try this, it throws the error `ValueError: could not convert string to float`. This might be a really dumb thing to say, but I'm not sure why the conversion would need to happen here, and why it's throwing that error: the anonymous function in `metric` can take strings and return a float; why do the inputs need to be floats, and how can I create this pairwise distance matrix based on simhash 'distances'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances.html), only metrics from `scipy.spatial.distance` are allowed, or a callable from:

```
In [26]: sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distance_functions
Out[26]:
{'cityblock': <function sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances>,
 'euclidean': <function sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances>,
 'l1': <function sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances>,
 'l2': <function sklearn.metrics.pairwise.euclidean_distances>,
 'manhattan': <function sklearn.metrics.pairwise.manhattan_distances>}
```

One issue is that if `metric` is `callable` then `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.check_pairwise_arrays` tries to convert the input to float, (`scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` does something similar, so you're out of luck there) thus your error.

Even if you *could* pass a callable it wouldn't scale very well, since the loop in `pairwise_distances` is pure Python. It looks like you'll have to just write the loop yourself. I would suggest reading the source code of `pdist` and/or `pairwise_distances` for hints as to how to do this.